# Регулярное выражение "\p{N}+" не находит числовые символы

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

[Согласно документации С#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-unicode-general-categories):

Регулярные выражения в C# поддерживают работу с общими категориями Юникода, среди которых есть:

> Nd - Число: десятичная цифра
>
> Nl - Число: буква
>
> No - Число: другое
>
> N - Все числа.All numbers. Включает категории Nd, Nl и No.

Для того, чтобы проверить утверждение о том, что регулярное выражение `\p{N}` может содержать в себе категории Nd, Nl и No, я написал код при помощи которого можно получить полный набор символов категории N:

```
// Get all Unicode groups:
Dictionary<UnicodeCategory, IGrouping<UnicodeCategory, string>> charInfo = (
      Enumerable.Range(0, 0x110000)
          .Where  (x => (x < 0x00D800 || x > 0x00DFFF))
          .Select (Char.ConvertFromUtf32)
          .GroupBy(s => Char.GetUnicodeCategory(s, 0))
          .ToDictionary(g => g.Key)
);

// Get all number unicode groups:
string[] Nd = charInfo[UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber].ToArray();
string[] Nl = charInfo[UnicodeCategory.LetterNumber      ].ToArray();
string[] No = charInfo[UnicodeCategory.OtherNumber       ].ToArray();

string[] N = Nd.Union(Nl).Union(No).ToArray();
```

Прогнав в NUnit тестах полученный набор символов группы `N` через регулярное выражение:

```
Regex.IsMatch(symbol, @"\p{N}+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

я получил результат в котором половина символов массива N не прошла проверку метода `Regex.IsMatch()`.

Пример символов которые не прошли проверку: , . Большая часть из них выглядит как:

Скажите пожалуйста, почему символы относящиеся к категории "числовые" не распознаются регулярным выражением `\p{N}+`?

Comment: Регулярные выражения .NET работают только с "Unicode code units", а не "Unicode code points", т.е. со строками в кодировке UTF16, и не "видят" двубайтовых символов.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Есть ли какой то способ отфильтровать полученные мной группы символов и получить только однобайтные?

Comment: У них `.Length = 1` .

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо. Совет с str.Length помог. Осталось только непонимание того, как в C# тестируют регулярные выражения которые должны взаимодействовать с "1<" байтовыми символами?

Comment: С помощью диапазонов однобайтовых символов.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: А хороший вопрос, почему никто не плюсует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Если коротко...

Значение объекта [Char](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char) представляет собой 16-разрядное числовое (порядковое) значение. Строки, кодируемые в UTF-16, позволяют использовать [суррогатные пары](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.char.issurrogatepair?view=netframework-4.7.2), состоящие из старшего и младшего знака-заменителя, каждый из которых представляет собой переменную типа `char`. Если подсчитать длину такого символа, `str.Length` вернёт `2`. По-английски, такой  знак определён как "code point", он состоит из двух "code unit", `\ud835` и `\udfec`.

Регулярные выражения в .NET не поддерживают суррогатные пары, то есть работает на уровне "code unit". Каждая из таких пар — это обычная последовательность 16-битных байтов для движка регулярных выражений.  Для того, чтобы найти их, нужно задать эти последовательности в виде диапазонов в символьных классах.

Демо такого регулярного выражения, находит все числовые символы:

```
\p{N}|\ud801[\udca0-\udca9]|\ud804[\udc66-\udc6f\udcf0-\udcf9\udd36-\udd3f\uddd0-\uddd9\udef0-\udef9\udc52-\udc65\udde1-\uddf4]|\ud805[\udcd0-\udcd9\ude50-\ude59\udec0-\udec9\udf30-\udf3b]|\ud806[\udce0-\udcf2]|\ud81a[\ude60-\ude69\udf50-\udf59\udf5b-\udf61]|\ud835[\udfce-\udfff]|\ud800[\udd40-\udd74\udf41\udf4a\udfd1-\udfd5\udd07-\udd33\udd75-\udd78\udd8a\udd8b\udee1-\udefb\udf20-\udf23]|\ud809[\udc00-\udc6e]|\ud802[\udc58-\udc5f\udc79-\udc7f\udca7-\udcaf\udcfb-\udcff\udd16-\udd1b\uddbc\uddbd\uddc0-\uddcf\uddd2-\uddff\ude40-\ude47\ude7d\ude7e\ude9d-\ude9f\udeeb-\udeef\udf58-\udf5f\udf78-\udf7f\udfa9-\udfaf]|\ud803[\udcfa-\udcff\ude60-\ude7e]|\ud834[\udf60-\udf71]|\ud83a[\udcc7-\udccf]|\ud83c[\udd00-\udd0c]
```

## Построение и тестирование шаблона

Я объявил следующие переменные:

```
var chrLst = new List<KeyValuePair<char, char>>(); // список суррогатных пар со старшим и младшим знаком
var testList = new List<string>(); // список символов для тестирования
var N_pattern_groups = new List<string>(); // список для создания шаблона регулярного выражения
```

Затем прогнал все знаки из `N` через следующий код:

```
foreach (var symbol in N)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(symbol, @"\p{N}"))
    {
        testList.Add(symbol); // заполняем список тестируемых символов
        var chrs = symbol.ToCharArray();
        chrLst.Add(new KeyValuePair<char, char>(chrs[0], chrs[1])); // Заполняем список суррогатных пар
        var hex = string.Concat(chrs.Select(x => string.Format(@"\u{0:x4}", (int)x))); // Получаем строку шестнадцатеричных значение обоих знаков 
        file.WriteLine($"{symbol}\t{hex}\t{char.IsSurrogatePair(symbol, 0)}"); // Сохранил информацию о символе в файл
    }
}
```

Файл для отладки содержит 708 символов при запуске в MS Visual Studio 2017, но всего 443 в [C# Mono на ideone.com](https://ideone.com/4xuCfd).

Далее, нужно построить шаблон. Для этого группируем список с ключами и значениями по ключу, строим диапазон из значений и соединяем всё в одно регулярное выражение:

```
var groups = chrLst.GroupBy(x => x.Key);
foreach (var grp in groups)
{
    N_pattern_groups.Add(string.Format(@"\u{0:x4}", (int)grp.Key) + CreateRangesFromList(grp.Select(x => x.Value).ToList()));
}
var N_pattern = string.Join("|", N_pattern_groups);
Console.WriteLine($"Pattern: {N_pattern}"); // Этот шаблон без \p{N}| приведён выше
```

Метод `CreateRangesFromList` выглядит не самым лучшим образом, но выполняет свою работу:

```
private string CreateRangesFromList(List<char> chrs)
{
    var tmp = "";
    var rngnum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < chrs.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((i < chrs.Count - 1) && (int)chrs[i] == ((int)chrs[i + 1]) - 1) {
            if (rngnum == 0)
            {
                tmp += string.Format(@"\u{0:x4}", (int)chrs[i]);
            }
            rngnum++;
        }
        else 
        {
            tmp += (rngnum > 1 ? "-" : "") + string.Format(@"\u{0:x4}", (int)chrs[i]);
            rngnum = 0;
        }
    }
    return $"[{tmp}]";
}
```

Проверка с помощью `bool check = testList.All(symbol => Regex.IsMatch(symbol, N_pattern));` показала, что всё работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]